# PhoneGap - Why Android Virtual Device not show the changes?

Tags: android, cordova, android-virtual-device

I installed the PhoneGap environment, update the SDK between API 8 to API 22 (with Android SDK Manager: all Tools and for each API, "DSK Platform" and "ARM...") and created a example project.

I created a AVD (Android Virtual Device) with AVD Manager in Eclipse, API 16 Android 4.1.2, launch the project in the AVD (Run As>Android Application) and I can see the project in the AVD but when I change the code and close the AVD and re-launch the example I can't see the changes (the option "build automatically" is marked). How is should work correctly the Android?

I instaled:
-NodeJs v0.12.2: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.2/x64/node-v0.12.2-x64.msi
-JDK for Win x64: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
-Apache Ant 1.9.4 Bin Zip: http://apache.spinellicreations.com//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.zip
-Adt-bundle: htps://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip
-And install PhoneGap with npm

In:
-Node Js: C:\Program Files\nodejs.
-Java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79.
-Apache Ant: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.4.
-ADT Bundle: C:\AndroidTools.
        -eclipse\
        -sdk\
        -workspace\

Environment variables:
User variables:
-PATH: C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\AndroidTools\sdk\tools;C:\AndroidTools\sdk\platform-tools;
System variables:
-ANDROID_HOME: C:\AndroidTools
-ANT_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.4
-JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
-NODE_PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\
-Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.4;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\AndroidTools\sdk\tools;C:\AndroidTools\sdk\platform-tools;C:\AndroidTools\sdk

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use Windows 8.1 64 bits, processor x64 i3 4005U, 4 GB DDR3 (1333 MHz) (more details of the machine http://www.solonotebooks.net/products/16396-toshiba-satellite-l45-b4205fl/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1.- Add a system variable was missing: e.g: ANDROID_PATH = C:\AndroidTools\sdk".

2.- Run this command to generate the app: "local phonegap build android" (located in the app directory, e.g: C:\AndroidTools\workspace\project).

With step two the files of the project will be generated in e.g: project\platforms\android\assets\www

3.- Launch the project in AVD.

I hope this helps someone ;)

Greetings!